# Do I need a CAML query if there is no restriction on the items I'm getting?

Tags: development, csom

I want to retrieve all list items in a SharePoint list that are in a column with internal name of LastName. A lot of examples I have seen on getting list items show how to write a CAML query but they are also getting specific items from a field (ex: LastName is Smith). This is the query I have:

```
CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
query.ViewXml = "<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='LastName'/></ViewFields></View>";
ListItemCollection items = templateList.GetItems(query);
```

My question is do I need to create a `CamlQuery` for this situation or is there a more efficient way to get the items in the field?

Comment: Do you only want items that have the LastName field populated? If so use IsNotNull https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms465807.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint CSOM List.GetItems must accept a CamlQuery object so you have to specify it.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.getitems.aspx

Or you could call REST API(/_api/web/lists('guid')/items?$select=LastName) by HttpWebRequest.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Roji.Joy/working-with-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-in-a-C-Sharp-managed-code/